# Making navbar fixed-top after scrolling past a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to make my bootstrap navbar become a fixed top navbar after scrolling down past a specific div.

Not sure what the best way to do this is, but my code is not adding the classes back onto the navbar after scrolling.

Any simpler solutions?

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

   // if on homepage
   if ( window.location.pathname == '/' ){


      $("#nav").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
      $("#nav").css("position", "absolute");

      $(window).scroll(function() {

       // get positions of nav and div element

       var thediv =$("#home-callout-top").offset();
       var thenav = $("#nav").offset();
       console.log("the div" + thediv.top + "nav" + thenav.top);

      if(thenav.top >= thediv.top){ 

            // If nav top position is greater (below) the div then make the navbar fixed top again

            $("#nav").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
            $("#nav").css("position", "relative");
      }
 });
 }
});
```

Comment: you meant `position:sticky` right?

Comment: Note that `position: sticky` only works in FF and Safari. For support in other browsers you'll need to roll your own solution

Comment: try position:fixed, top:0; left:0

Comment: using chrome, its needs to work on most recent broswers